# The song "..." could not be used because the original file could not be found. Would you like to locate it?

Tags: music

I know that the question's title is repeated, but what I found here were answers for iTunes, and I tried them, but it didn't work.

Basically, the following happened: I had about 50 GB of MP3s in the ~/Music directory and deleted them because Apple Music said they were already in the cloud.

My other MacBook plays the music without any problems, streaming, but on this MacBook, it displays the warning from the question's title.

My question is: Without downloading, how can I listen to music via streaming without the Music app showing the warning?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you deleted the music using the Finder or Terminal, instead of through the Apple Music app. Deleting them this way means Apple Music doesn't know you've deleted the files, hence the dialog boxes that pop up asking you to locate the track you're playing.

To solve, use Apple Music to select the tracks you want to listen to only via streaming and right-click > Remove download. This is easiest in the Song view with Column Browser enabled for drilling down to the tracks you want.

In this view there's a Cloud Download column, which you can enable if it isn't already visible by right-clicking the column headings above the list of tracks. You can then click the Cloud Download column heading (a cloud symbol) to sort your library by cloud download status. Downloaded tracks show with a white down arrow inside a grey circle. You may also find the Cloud Status column useful, which shows whether tracks are matched, uploaded, from Apple Music and so on.

Comment: It worked, thank you!